# Data alignment inside expandable table in Vuetify2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using official example of expanded table (v-data-table) in Vuetify2. I want to show nested table on row click. Here is what I get:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrWbu.jpg)

As you can see the column width of nested table does not match the column width of root table.

Here's the code:

```html
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-xs-right"><strong>Row1</strong></td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-xs-right"><strong>Row2</strong></td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">1234</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
</template>
```

And here's the 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/alexatiks/pen/WNeMXyd?editors=1010)

Please suggest, how I can achieve data alignment without hardcoding. Thanks.

Comment: Your child table doesn't know about layout of parent table, so it will be hard to keep them aligned without resorting to javascript. As an alternative you might want to try keeping expandable rows in same table, just toggle visibility - that way column sizes will be aligned. But you'll have to write your own styles for expanded rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @joshas. I'll try the second way.